# Handle xml response with php

Tags: php, xml, curl, response

I'm using the code below to fetch xml data. I can't do it any other way, as I use it to my iOS app and I'm receiving the response as an xml element, as I expected. When I run it in the browser I see only the values of xml nodes.

For example this is my xml:

```
<Message version="1.0" messageId="12">
<SaleResponse>
<OrderId>1234</OrderId>
<OrderAmount>1.0</OrderAmount>
</SaleResponse>
</Message>
```

This is exactly the output I get in my ios app but in my browser I get this:

> 12341.0

This is my php code:

```
<?php

      $url = 'https://something.com';

            $ch = curl_init($url);

            $inp = $_REQUEST["xmlpost"];

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                               'Content-type: application/xml',
                               'TX_URL: something.com',
                               'TX_TokenExID: something',
                               'TX_APIKey: something' ));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $inp);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            echo $result;
    ?>
```

So how can I handle `result` as xml and take every tag separately?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

Comment: I'd suggest to remove the question to avoid downvotes

Comment: @AlexBlex I'm searching for hours at this site but the only I can get is a ready xml with a specific start and finish, If you could suggest me something more specific I'll be glad

Comment: What you see on the page is how **browser** handles xml. If you check page source, you will see raw xml as it was printed by your script. If you need to manipulate xml, please read the docs behind the link. "research efforts" are not limited to the search on SO, but also reading the docs. The question in its current edition clearly shows lack of research efforts in that direction.

Comment: You are right I did an inspect element and I saw the xml, but still I can't find something that can help me handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your string through the php function `simplexml_load_string`:

```
$result = simplexml_load_string($result);
echo $result->SaleResponse->OrderId


<?php
//or in an actual example

$string = '<Message version="1.0" messageId="12">
<SaleResponse>
<OrderId>1234</OrderId>
<OrderAmount>1.0</OrderAmount>
</SaleResponse>
</Message>';
$obj= simplexml_load_string($string);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not working as I tested before I saw that the format of the xml that it takes has to start like this <<<XML and finish like this xml;

Comment: The <<<XML is heredoc syntax.  You don't need that because your string is coming in from a CURL call.  Look at my example above.

Comment: Ok I found out what I was missing, My xml started with vpos tag (this way I took it to my ios app too) but when I printed result with print_r I saw that it wasn't taking the first tag (vpos) Thanks for the help

Comment: `print_r` is your friend